# Check whether the writing permission was accepted or denied

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am currently trying to implement a trading system for my unity android app using firebase.
For that I have to check, if a player pressed the buy button for one trade, if the selected trade is still available in the firebase database.

The way it is supposed to work is, that the player who wants to buy something checks in the corresponding trade, if the buyerId is still empty, and if so puts his own id in there.
I've set up the firebase rules, so that the buyerId and buyerName can only be set once.

So that's now the code I was trying to use:

```
if (!reference.Child("trading").Child("trade|" + currentTrade.date).Child("buyerId").SetValueAsync(userId).IsCanceled)
{
    Debug.Log("trade should be successfull");
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("trade should have failed");
}
```

Well the problem is now, that it doesn't matter if the buyerId is empty or not, the unity console always prints out, that the trade was succesfully. But I do actually get a logWarning in the console, that the permission was denied. My question is now, how do I detect it properly if the buyerId was already set?

My database structure:

```
{
  "currentVersion" : {
    "FileSize" : 58010,
    "ReleaseDate" : "01.08.19",
    "Version" : "1.10.7.9"
  },
  "trading" : {
    "trade|1570361586" : {
      "amount" : 5,
      "buyerId" : "",
      "buyerName" : "",
      "date" : 1570361586,
      "item" : 7,
      "price" : 6,
      "sellerId" : "1234",
      "sellerName" : "testA"
    },
    "trade|1570363226" : {
      "amount" : 1,
      "buyerId" : "9876",
      "buyerName" : "testB",
      "date" : 1570363226,
      "item" : 7,
      "price" : 1,
      "sellerId" : "1234",
      "sellerName" : "testA"
    },
    "trade|1570467885" : {
      "amount" : 1,
      "buyerId" : "4545",
      "buyerName" : "testC",
      "date" : 1570467885,
      "item" : 7,
      "price" : 2,
      "sellerId" : "1234",
      "sellerName" : "testA"
    }
  }
}
```

My database rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
    "currentVersion" : {
        ".write" : false,
        ".read" : true     
    },
    "trading" : {
      ".read" : true,
      "$trade" : {
        ".write" : "!data.exists()",
        "buyerName" : {
          ".write" : "data.val() == '' && newData.val() != ''"
        },
        "buyerId" : {
          ".write" : "data.val() == '' && newData.val() != ''"
        },
        "sellerName" : {
          ".write" : false
        },
        "sellerId" : {
          ".write" : false
        },
        "amount" : {
          ".write" : false
        },
        "item" : {
          ".write" : false
        },
        "price" : {
          ".write" : false
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've added the json data in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks odd to me:

```
if (!reference.Child("trading").Child("trade|" + currentTrade.date).Child("buyerId")
  .SetValueAsync(userId).IsCanceled)
```

Since you're calling `SetValueAsync`, the value is set to the database asynchronously. The chances of `IsCanceled` being `true` right after your call to `SetValueAsync` are incredibly small.

As the documentation on [knowing when your data is committed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#know_when_your_data_is_committed) explains, you'll want to wait until the `Task` that is returned from `SetValueAsync` is completed.

Something like this:

```
reference.Child("trading").Child("trade|" + currentTrade.date).Child("buyerId")
  .SetValueAsync(userId).).ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            // Handle the error...
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I do still have one problem. Your solution is working fine for me, if I delete the ".write" : "!data.exists()" part in the firebase rules. And as a result, a player can't add new trades to the database. So what part of the rules do I have to change, so that a player can always add new trades, but only change existing trades, if the buyerId isn't already set?

Comment: Well it seems like I've found the answer to that issue. I've quickly buileded an apk and tested it on my android device, where everything is working as it should be. So the problem only occures, when I am using the unity editor. Thanks again for your help.